How to remove an instance of a widget
I am creating an editor and I have multiple widgets in it, using the stack_board package. I want to stop move gesture if the widget is not selected.
Here is the code:
    class _ItemCaseState extends State<ItemCase> with SafeState<ItemCase> {
     
      bool isWidgetSelected = false;
    void _onTap() {
    
        if (widget.tapToEdit) {
          if (_operatState != OperatState.editing) {
            _operatState = OperatState.editing;
            safeSetState(() {});
          }
        } else if (_operatState == OperatState.complate) {
          safeSetState(() {
            _operatState = OperatState.idle;
            isWidgetSelected = true;
          });
        }
    
        widget.onTap?.call();
    
        widget.onOperatStateChanged?.call(_operatState);
      }
    
     void _moveHandle(DragUpdateDetails dud) {
       
        if (!isWidgetSelected) {
          return;
        }
        
        if (_operatState != OperatState.moving) {
          if (_operatState == OperatState.scaling ||
              _operatState == OperatState.roating) {
            _operatState = OperatState.moving;
          } else {
            _operatState = OperatState.moving;
             safeSetState(() {});
          }
    
          widget.onOperatStateChanged?.call(_operatState);
        }
    
       
      }
    }

I have a variable isWidgetSelected and I make it true on tap and return flow on move gesture, but in this case:
If I select one widget it works fine, but then I select another widget then it's value remains true for the first one (it doesn't update) , not the for selected one
I have tried using for loop for all the elements and it's also not working:
`editorController.stackboardIdsList.forEach((itemId) {
      isWidgetSelected = false;
    });`

